# SQLite triggers or similar for executing android code

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm starter with databases and I'd need some help :)
I'm attempting to implement the archievement system in my app.
What I have basically is a table with user statistics like that:
stat_id, stat_description, stat_integer_value

I need to increase or decrease the stat_integer_value an ammount of units and execute some code (for save the archievement as awarded and make a toast) when it go over a fixed value)

What I would do is, when the stat is modified
value = SQLquery the current value
newvalue= value + change
if (newvalue> threshold) {
    SQL insert (in awards table)
    maketoast()
}
SQLupdate (newvalue)

I have to execute that code very often so I'd like to optimize it, is there any way?
I have read about triggers, but a trigger only execute instructions within the database right?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could keep your values in memory (in a variable or array), and commit them to the database in `onResume()` - that's what I'm doing when I need to access the database often.

Answer (score 0):

In your description, I know when the database record is changed, the SQL trigger is executed.
The logic is right; I have a question, when do you modify the DB? I consider this is more important. you should according to particular case optimize it.